# Calling a service class from a controller results in On object reference is required for the non-static field, method error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I have a controller action that performs a particular task. I am trying to execute another method in  a different class. I happen to be trying to use Hangfire, but that is not relevant to the issue I don't think.

The code won't compile because the method call `UpdatePlayerStats.Process(originalresult.Id);` errors with `On object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property call ...`

How can I make this work?

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CommitScorecard(ScorecardViewModel vm)
{
    //Other code

    UpdatePlayerStats.Process(originalresult.Id);

    //With hangfire
    var jobId = _backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => UpdatePlayerStats.Process(originalresult.Id));
    
    //Other code
}
```

**Service**

```
public class UpdatePlayerStats
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UpdatePlayerStats(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Process(long resultid)
    {
        var result = _context.Results.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == resultid);
        return true;
    }     
}
```

Comment: *"How can I make this work?"* - Either the `Process` method would need to be `static` or the controller needs an instance of `UpdatePlayerStats` on which to invoke the method.  Which is "better" is a matter of opinion and consistency with the rest of your design.  In general the common approach is to use the framework's dependency injection to provide instances of service classes to controllers.  (Much in the same way that it appears you are relying on dependency injection to provide a DB Context to the service.)  That's very likely to be the ideal approach here as well.